# Get description of packages in yocto image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I know I can get a list of packages included in an image using this command:

```
bitbake -g <image> && cat pn-buildlist | grep -ve "native" | sort | uniq
```

Is there a bitbake command to get the description of a specific package? Or perhaps there is a command to get all info on a package, I could simply grep the output of this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a bitbake command, but there is `oe-pkgdata-util` utility (part of openembedded-core). It works in OE build environment (like bitbake). You can query a value from a built package (not recipe) using the `read-value` subcommand. The basic syntax is:

```
oe-pkgdata-util read-value <value> <pkg1> [<pkg2>...]
```

You can query multiple packages, prefix the name of package etc. Just check:

```
oe-pkgdata-util read-value --help
```

Here is an example for your question:

```
tom@pc:~/oe/build> oe-pkgdata-util read-value DESCRIPTION libc6
The GNU C Library is used as the system C library in most systems with the Linux kernel.
```

BTW, you can query other variables like `RDEPENDS`, `SUMMARY` etc.

Please note that if the `DESCRIPTION` variable is not set in the recipe, it is filled with content of a `SUMMARY` variable ([see doc](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DESCRIPTION)).

---

Your question also mentions getting the list of packages in the image. I would say that there are more straightforward ways. For example:

1. manifest file in the deploy dir (the file is next to the image file): `${DEPLOY_DIR}/images/${MACHINE}/${IMAGE_BASENAME}-${MACHINE}.manifest`
2. file `installed-package-names.txt` in buildhistory (if you've enabled it). It is inside the folder `${BUILDHISTORY_DIR}/images/${MACHINE_ARCH}/${TCLIBC}/${IMAGE_BASENAME}/`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, not every package has a description.
I usually read the recipe as it is faster than waiting the bitbake output. Nevertheless, if you wish to read it from bitbake:

```
bitbake <recipe> -e | grep ^DESCRIPTION=
```

The description may be written in the recipe, like in [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/ifupdown/ifupdown_0.8.16.bb)

As a side note, you can get access to each variable with `-e`, very useful for debugging.